# Hadoop DistributedCache causes IOException

Tags: hadoop, distributed-cache

I have written some code to do a selfjoin task using Hadoop. For this purpose I use DistributedCache class.When I run the code locally in Netbeans the job is done correctly but when I try to run it in a single node cluster after I upload the data in hdfs I get the following Exception:

```
Error initializing attempt_201301021509_0002_m_000002_0:
java.io.IOException: Distributed cache entry arrays have different lengths: 1, 2, 1, 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.downloadPrivateCacheObjects(JobLocalizer.java:316)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.downloadPrivateCache(JobLocalizer.java:343)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.localizeJobFiles(JobLocalizer.java:388)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobLocalizer.localizeJobFiles(JobLocalizer.java:367)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.DefaultTaskController.initializeJob(DefaultTaskController.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$4.run(TaskTracker.java:1228)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:416)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1203)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1118)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$5.run(TaskTracker.java:2430)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679)
```

I understand that the problem is in the JobLocalizer.java and the `DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf)` that returns 2 but I don't know the reason why this happen. Could anyone tell me what I don't get?

PS: I forgot to mention that I use Hadoop-1.0.4

PS2: The problem is that `DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(conf)` sees the real input file and also a temp file that is the same as the input file and is temporarily stored in /tmp folder. That happens when I run it locally (which does not throw any exception). I guess sth similar happens when I run it from hdfs but then it throws the exception. Is there any ideas how could I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It is probably happening as you are providing the local path to the file rather than moving the file to HDFS and then providing the HDFS path. Also I believe you are trying it out locally and running hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode.

In order to move a file to hdfs you can do something like following :

```
$ hadoop fs -put <your-file-path> <someHDFSfoldername/filename>
```

And then add `someHDFSfoldername/filename` in your Distributed cache.

EDIT:
Looking at the code [here](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobLocalizer.java) , it happens when there is a mismatch in the number of source and destination files. Following code segment from [JobLocalizer.java](https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/JobLocalizer.java) is getting you the error:

```
if (sources.length != dests.length ||
        sources.length != times.length ||
        sources.length != isPublic.length) {
      throw new IOException("Distributed cache entry arrays have different " +
                            "lengths: " + sources.length + ", " + dests.length +
                            ", " + times.length + ", " + isPublic.length);
    }
```

If you get us more info on how are you adding the cache files and how are you accessing them it would help.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I indeed run hadoop in pseudo-distributed mode (I 've also tried the same code in a real cluster and had the same results). I am sure that I have uploaded my input file in hdfs and I pass the path as argument in the jar.The problem is that getLocalCacheFiles in JobLocalizer returns two paths, the one is the real "input.txt" and there is an extra file that called "fileinput.txt" and I don't know what this file is.

Comment: is it possible then that you are adding a folder instead of a file!! But that too doesn't sound well. It's very weird! show me how you are adding and retrieving it, there is certainly somewhere some silly mistake.

Comment: No i just add the text file. I tried both -put and -copyFromLocal but nothing works.Also `hadoop fs -ls <path/input>` shows only the correct file and no extra files. Any other suggestions?

Comment: When I say -put and -copyFromLocal do not work I mean that I still get the exception and not that the input data are not been uploaded in hdfs (which they do, as I said before). :)